# Не показываются дроп-дауны на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css

На десктопе все отлично, и даже через гугл адаптацию для мобильных устройств все проходит нормально, но как я начинаю выкладывать это на гит пейдж - так сразу на моем айфон 14 про ничего не видно при нажатии на главные кнопки (дроп-даунов нет)

```js
const toggleMenu = () => {
  const body = document.body;
  body.classList.toggle("open");

  // Проверка, открыто ли меню
  if (body.classList.contains("open")) {
    // Заблокировать прокрутку страницы
    body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    // Разблокировать прокрутку страницы
    body.style.overflow = "";
  }
};
```

```css
.navbar,
.navbar-burger,
.menu {
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1501;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.navbar-burger {
  z-index: 1501;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 88px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url("./assets/menu.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  background-position: center;
  transition: filter 0.3s;
}

.navbar-burger:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

body.open .navbar-burger {
  background-image: url("./assets/close.svg");
}

.menu {
  z-index: 1200;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.959);
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body.open .menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu nav:hover a {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.menu nav:hover .dropbtn {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.menu nav .dropbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 280px;
  /* Установите фиксированное расстояние здесь */
  top: 50%;
  /* Выравнивание по середине кнопки */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Смещение вверх на половину высоты элемента */
}

.dropdown a {
  position: relative;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu .dropbtn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu .dropbtn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

body.open .menu .dropbtn {
  animation: appear 0.3s backwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    translate: 0 50px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 120%;
  /* Позиционирование выпадающего меню справа */
  top: 50%;
  /* Выравнивание по середине кнопки */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Смещение вверх на половину высоты элемента */
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  /* Установи цвет текста на белый */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  animation: appear 0.3s backwards;
  margin-left: 14vw;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn:focus+.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Добавьте стили для кнопки */

.dropbtn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  /* Установите цвет текста на белый */
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 4em;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown .fa-chevron-right {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  /* Регулируйте это значение для изменения расстояния стрелки от текста кнопки */
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown:hover .fa-chevron-right,
.dropdown .dropbtn:focus .fa-chevron-right {
  transform: translateX(5px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .dropbtn {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: -200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  .dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: -100px;
  }
  .dropbtn {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .dropbtn {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .menu {
    z-index: 1200;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    place-items: flex start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* Сохраняет высоту */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.959);
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .dropbtn {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-burger" onclick="toggleMenu()"></button>
<div class="menu">
  <nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" style="animation-delay: 0.1s">О нас <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Подменю 1</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 2</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 3</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" style="animation-delay: 0.2s">Грант <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Подменю 1</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 2</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 3</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" style="animation-delay: 0.2s">Поступление <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Подменю 1</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 2</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 3</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn" style="animation-delay: 0.4s">Новости</a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="dropbtn" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">Контакты</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">Родителям <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Подменю 1</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 2</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 3</a>
        <a href="#">Подменю 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```